# React native slow perfomance on calendars

Tags: performance, reactjs, user-interface, optimization, react-native

I have tried many open source RN Calendar components out there and all of them seem to have performance issues.

I built my own `CalendarList` with a simple grid layout using `FlexBox` inside a `FlatList`, and it also becomes **unusable** due to rendering Performance issues.

There are around **1200 Views** (13 months shown x 85 views p/month ) components according to the Perf Monitor. It seems the Bridge gets jammed when updating the 1200

It seems the issue is that a calendar has around 300 components which RN can't update without jamming the JS thread.

**Workarounds i tried:**

- Using setNativeProps to perform update.
- Using `getItemLayout` for skipping `FlatList` measurements.
- Caching components (Not react way of doing things)
- Made all my components PureComponents which are faster.
- Displaying a Placeholder waiting for the calendar to render (not pretty and still jams the UI)

I wonder how people use a calendar lists in React Native, as i can't make any perform fast.

Comment: tried this: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars ? . Loading a very large list will take sometime. If u are using flat list limit  the initial size to render.

Comment: That is the first component i tried and it is very slow and unusable in old devices like an iPhone 5S. It becomes jammed really hard and will stop rendering. I wanted to use that one but has the same issues. Also my initialRender size is 3,  the loading i managed to optimize it but updating the calendar day boxes takes forever for React. (something like Greying out dates)

Comment: I tried it in slow android devices .. rendering works normal. Updating the calendar dates is tricky. you can't just update everything. you need to use some some criteria like : Updates dates in a month when month gets changed, instead of doing everything

Comment: That would be a nice solution but how can you tell the Flatlist to only update certain rows and not all of them?

Comment: on iPhone 5 RN directly crashes

Comment: Any news? Still very slow.

Comment: This was long time ago but I ended up implementing my own calendar with some optimizations and made it run faster. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-list